# upload not saved bitmap to server

Tags: android, file-upload, bitmap

i'm using the below code to get an image from video that i want to upload it to server and the image will be my thumbnail image there ... it works correctly and shows the image in ImageView ... but some thing that is wrong is I can't upload it without saving on SD Card ... is there any way for me to upload Bitmap image directly to server without SD Card URI?

My Code:

```
private void chooseVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a Video "), SELECT_VIDEO);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {
            System.out.println("SELECT_VIDEO");
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            textView.setText(selectedPath);

            bt = createVideoThumbnail(this, selectedImageUri);
            iv_image.setImageBitmap(bt);
        }
    }
}

public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail(Context context, Uri uri) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
        bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(-1);
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        // Assume this is a corrupt video file.
    } finally {
        try {
            retriever.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            // Ignore failures while cleaning up.
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
 byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
 String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Then POST the image_str to the server, base64 decode it back to an image.